# How to output a variable in a button group to influence a dropdown result in Angular.js and Html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my work so far:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="dataCtrl">
    <h2>Test</h2>

    <h4>Select Category</h4>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-repeat="categories in model">
            <a data-toggle="pill" href="">{{categories.catName}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <h4>Select Trend</h4>
    <select class="form-control" id="trendID" ng-repeat="categories in model">
        <option ng-repeat="trends in categories.trends">{{trends.trendName}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The dataCtrl brings in a model with all the data necessary for running this little test program.  I have tested that the data by running a {{model | json}} and seeing the data listed, so I know the data is ok.

All the buttons in 'Category' are labelled correctly as are the dropdown menus.

[image: Screenshot]

My intention is for the user to select a category, which will reveal a dropdown menu (I intend to use ng-if to accomplish this).  However, I am having some difficulty in getting a value from the button.  I have tried:

```
ng-click="{{categories.catID}}"
```

But that never works.  I have also tried building a new controller, however that keeps causing the whole thing to fall apart.  I have requested assistance on this, and although they look sound, when I apply them they don't seem to work.

My 'app.js' currently has two functioning controllers including dataCtrl, so I know that I am doing all that without error.  It is only when I attempt to add a button controller does the whole thing fall apart.

I would appreciate if someone could just assist me on this and explain the hows and whys, so that I might learn something from this.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

In summary, what you are trying to do is filter your dropdowns based on what category is selected. Therefore you need somewhere to store the selected value. Then after you have a selected value you can set it via your pill button. Finally, you can control which is visible via ng-if.

dataCtrl:

```
$scope.selectedCategoryId = null;
```

pill button:

```
<a data-toggle="pill" href="" ng-click="selectedCategoryId = categories.catID">{{categories.catName}}</a>
```

dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control" id="trendID" ng-repeat="categories in model" ng-if="categories.catID == selectedCategoryId">
    <option ng-repeat="trends in categories.trends">{{trends.trendName}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ok. I'm going to create a new controller for this.  Thank you for your suggestions, it's good to know I am on track as they are pretty much what I have been doing.  My issue is probably more about the controller itself, although the ng-click you have recommended is different to my first attempts.

Comment: @TJSUK I am unsure why you would need to create another controller for this. I think that would be needlessly complicating things.

Comment: I'm creating a new controller to handle the states of the buttons and drop menus. I have three button groups and a drop menu. Setting up a single controller to handle all these is good MVC. DataCtrl handles my Json information.

Comment: Ok. I have tried using that suggestion.  However, the selectedCategoryId variable is not updating when clicking on one of the categories buttons.  It is allowing the variable to exist, it's just not updating.

Comment: I have fixed it, thank you. I have worked out the answer.  Your first and third parts work a treat, so thank you. Although I couldn't get your second part to work, I have found a work around.  I will post as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<h2>Test</h2>
<section title="UserInput" ng-controller="evPotCatBtnCtrl as formState">

    <h4>Select Category</h4>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-repeat="item in model" ng-class="{'active':rowIndex == $index }" ng-click="selectRow($index, model)">
            <a href="">{{item.catID+" "+item.catName}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <h4>Select Trend</h4>
    <select class="form-control" id="trendID" ng-repeat="categories in model" ng-if="categories.catID == selCatID">
        <option ng-repeat="trends in categories.Trends">{{trends.trendName}}</option>
    </select>
</section>
```

Angular Controller:

```
angular.module('CatButtonController', [])

    .controller("CatBtnCtrl",['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.rowIndex = -1;
        $scope.selCatID = 0;

        $scope.selectRow = function (index, model) {
            if (index == $scope.rowIndex)
                $scope.rowIndex = -1;
            else {
                console.log(model[index].catID);
                $scope.rowIndex = index;
                $scope.selCatID = model[index].catID;
            }

        };
}]);
```